# Overwrite the global database driver

Tags: database, jfactory, unit-testing

`JFactory` has a `getDbo` method, but no `setDbo`. Why? It can be useful for unit-testing to be able to overwrite the global database driver. Any other way to do this?

**EDIT:** `$database` is a public property of `JFactory`, so I can just overwrite it like so:

```
$myDatabase = new JDatabaseDriver ...
JFactory::$database = $myDatabase;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the database driver, just not with any simple function (that I know of), such as `setDbo`.

If you look at the [Joomla Database Framework package](https://github.com/joomla-framework/database):

```
use Joomla\Database;

class MyApplication extends AbstractApplication
{
    protected $db;

    protected function initialise()
    {
        // Make the database driver.
        $dbFactory = new Database\DatabaseFactory;

        $this->db = $dbFactory->getDriver(
            $this->get('database.driver'),
            array(
                'host' => $this->get('database.host'),
                'user' => $this->get('database.user'),
                'password' => $this->get('database.password'),
                'port' => $this->get('database.port'),
                'socket' => $this->get('database.socket'),
                'database' => $this->get('database.name'),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

So you can replace `$this->get('database.driver')` with the driver that you need.

Comment: Not possible in my case, since all methods in my class is static (helper class that's is called from all manner of places). But it seems that `JFactory::$database` is a public property, so I can just overwrite it.

Comment: Well, of course it's possible, but such code would better be placed in a constructor, of which I never call. So.